# How to display related data in dropdown list by selecting specific data from corresponding dropdown list

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am using Drupal7,in that i have module where in i have written my own functions using php,with two dropdown list in row, now my requirement is when i select for example say "A" from 1st drop down then in 2nd drop down only related to "A" all data need show in the second dropdown, 
In simple words if i select the city name from the 1st dropdown, then all the colleges of that city should display in 2nd dropdown.How can i achieve this in php?i found this link and piece of code http://w3shaman.com/article/creating-ajax-dropdown-drupal-7 but no use, it will be great helpful for me if someone answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you created your form using Drupal Form API, then you can achive this using the Drupal Ajax.
Below is a code snippet from the Drupal Ajax examples module

```
function ajax_example_dependent_dropdown($form, &$form_state) {
  // Get the list of options to populate the first dropdown.
  $options_first = _ajax_example_get_first_dropdown_options();
  // If we have a value for the first dropdown from $form_state['values'] we use
  // this both as the default value for the first dropdown and also as a
  // parameter to pass to the function that retrieves the options for the
  // second dropdown.
  $selected = isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_first']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_first'] : key($options_first);
  $form['dropdown_first'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Instrument Type',
    '#options' => $options_first,
    '#default_value' => $selected,
    // Bind an ajax callback to the change event (which is the default for the
    // select form type) of the first dropdown. It will replace the second
    // dropdown when rebuilt.
    '#ajax' => array(
      // When 'event' occurs, Drupal will perform an ajax request in the
      // background. Usually the default value is sufficient (eg. change for
      // select elements), but valid values include any jQuery event,
      // most notably 'mousedown', 'blur', and 'submit'.
      // 'event' => 'change',
      'callback' => 'ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'dropdown-second-replace',
    ),
  );

  $form['dropdown_second'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $options_first[$selected] . ' ' . t('Instruments'),
    // The entire enclosing div created here gets replaced when dropdown_first
    // is changed.
    '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-second-replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    // When the form is rebuilt during ajax processing, the $selected variable
    // will now have the new value and so the options will change.
    '#options' => _ajax_example_get_second_dropdown_options($selected),
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_second']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_second'] : '',
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );
  return $form;
}    

function ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['dropdown_second'];
}

function _ajax_example_get_second_dropdown_options($key = '') {
  $options = array(
    t('String') => drupal_map_assoc(
    array(
      t('Violin'),
      t('Viola'),
      t('Cello'),
      t('Double Bass'),
    )
    ),
    t('Woodwind') => drupal_map_assoc(
    array(
      t('Flute'),
      t('Clarinet'),
      t('Oboe'),
      t('Bassoon'),
    )
    ),
    t('Brass') => drupal_map_assoc(
    array(
      t('Trumpet'),
      t('Trombone'),
      t('French Horn'),
      t('Euphonium'),
    )
    ),
    t('Percussion') => drupal_map_assoc(
    array(
      t('Bass Drum'),
      t('Timpani'),
      t('Snare Drum'),
      t('Tambourine'),
    )
    ),
  );
  if (isset($options[$key])) {
    return $options[$key];
  }
  else {
    return array();
  }
}
```